# Tomorrow will be Muggy, followed by Tuggy, Wuggy and Thuggy

Tags: british-english

I read [an article](http://beatles.wikia.com/wiki/John_Lennon), here is the original words:

> Lennon even created his own comic strip, which he called "The Daily Howl". This contained drawings, frequently of crippled people, and satirical writings, often with a play on words. For example, in one page, Lennon wrote a weather report saying that "Tomorrow will be Muggy, followed by Tuggy, Wuggy and Thuggy".

Could someone tell me about the meaning of ""Tomorrow will be Muggy, followed by Tuggy, Wuggy and Thuggy"? This is hard to understand for me since English is not my mother language.

Comment: The [actual wording](http://www.thebeatleschronology.com/dailyhowl13.jpg) was "Tomorrow will be Muggy, followed by Tuggy, Weggy, Thurggy and Friggy".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Tomorrow will be muggy" is a typical weather forecast.

> **muggy** *adjective* (**muggier, muggiest**)
>   (of the weather) unpleasantly warm and humid:
>   *it was a hot, very muggy evening*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/muggy?q=muggy)

*Muggy* also sounds a little like *Monday*, which is followed by Tuesday, Wednesday etc. It's possible that someone with a speech impediment might even pronounce *Monday* as *Muggy*. The cartoon plays on that relationship and creates days in the same way: *Tuggy, Wuggy, Thuggy...*

It would appear that featuring disabilities is a common theme in the cartoons.

Answer (score 7):

> Generally muggy means  ***being warm, damp, and close***

For ex.

> a muggy day in August
>
> [Reference for Muggy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muggy)

But here author/writer suggest that in comical way like

> muggy for Monday
>
> Tuggy for Tuesday
>
> Wuggy for Wednesday

and

> Thuggy for Thursday.

Hot/warm days in August.

Comment: He could have continued "Fruggy", "Stuggy" and (with a little poetic license) "Snuggy"

Comment: It's reminiscent of George Ellis' parody of the French republican calendar of 1793: Ellis, an English poet deeply hostile to French revolutionary pretensions, translates d'Églantine's efforts (his names reflect the changing weather and crops of the year - Vendémiaire, Brumaire, Frimaire (the autumn), Nivôse, Pluviôse, Ventôse (winter), Germinal, Floréal, Prairial (spring), Messidor, Thermidor, Fructidor (summer) with: (Jan...) 'Snowy, Flowy, Blowy, Showery, Flowery, Bowery, Hoppy, Croppy, Droppy, Breezy, Sneezy, Freezy'. http://www.historyworld.net/wrldhis/PlainTextHistories.asp?historyid=102